# Angular - Render HTML inside <p> tag

Tags: html, angular, innerhtml

I want to render some html table and some data inside a `<p>` tag in Angular

In my `report.component.html`

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
  <div class="ui-g-12" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <p-fieldset legend="{{item.recordTime}}" [toggleable]="true" [collapsed]="true">
      <div class="overflow">
        <p [innerHTML]="item.message"></p>
      </div>
    </p-fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my `report.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.listAllReports();
}

  listAllReports() {
    this.httpSvc.fetchWithoutSpinner(this.urlBuilder.getAllReportUrl()).subscribe(data => {
      data.forEach(report => {
        const newReport= new Report();
        newReport.message = '<table style="font-family: arial, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;"> <tr> <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">Item1</th> <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">Item2</th> <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">Item3</th> <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">Item4</th> <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">Item5</th> <th style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">Item6</th> </tr><tr> <td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">238342</td><td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">000</td><td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">807</td><td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">ZZZZ</td><td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">XXX</td><td style="border: 1px solid #dddddd; text-align: left; padding: 8px;">YYY</td></tr></table>';
        newReport.recordTime = report.recordTime;
        this.items.push(newReport);
      });
    });
  }
```

Note that in the `newReport.message`, inside has some html codes that should be rendered.

But the table is not rendered:

[image]

Where is my mistakes?

Comment: Look at the [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) for your answer

Comment: I recently stumbled upon this. I solved it by declaring a `ViewChild()` for my `p`-tag (let's call it `inlineP`) and inlining the HTML via `inlineP.nativeElement.innerHTML  = <your html value>`. You have to do this in `ngAfterViewInit()`.

Comment: Does items equal to reportList?

Comment: @ahmeticat sorry my mistake, i updated the question, yes it is.

Comment: @ValentinoRu sorry i am new to angular, so i not really sure what you mean, do you have a simple code snippet that able to explain? Thanks

Comment: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer check this

Comment: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Qke2jktna55h40ubUl8o?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview

Comment: Please remember to mark the correct answer so anyone that lands up here can find the solution easily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a custom Angular pipe to bypass the security for the html.

Your HTML will be like this

```
<div [innerHTML]="item.message | TrustHtml"></div>
```

And the Pipe will be as follows

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'TrustHtml',
    pure: true // This allows the pipe to only run once
})
export class TrustHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    }

    transform(pUnsafe: string) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(pUnsafe);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to change that pipe name to `TrustHtml`, to be more truthy to its purpose

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work [see](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qz4ysm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)
Change 'items' to 'reportList' and call domSanitzer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml() and you html.

```
 *ngFor="let item of reportList"
```

Answer (score 0):

Bypassing sanitizer to trust any content can be a security concern. Since Angular is not a dedicated sanitizing library, it is overzealous towards suspicious content to not take any risks. It removed almost all attributes, for example. You can delegate sanitizing to a dedicated library — DOMPurify. Here's a wrapper library I've made to easily use DOMPurify with Angular:

https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/ng-dompurify